# why only javascript needs prototype?

Tags: javascript

Reading some articles, which said Javascript use prototype to keep instance method or property only one copy.

I got quite confused; why the language like C++, C# or Java does not need prototype? if there are thousands of instances, does those languages will duplicate method thousands of times?

Answer (score 0):

No, other languages have analogous mechanisms for avoiding duplication of methods on instances of a class. With JavaScript, this is simply more exposed/manual than it is for other languages.

Answer (score 0):

In mentioned languages `class` works instead of `prototype` in javascript. Mind that these languages are compiled, which means before execution the compiler needs to go over the whole program and collect all metadata. The pointers  to member functions are stored in special in-memory tables, and all the object has is a reference to that table. Besides they are so called *strongly typed* languages. Which means once you defined members of a class you cannot change it at run-time.

Javascript is definitely not the case. It is closer to interpreter. It only requires pre-compilation of a function not the whole program. Besides the dynamic nature of javascript requires to have explicit access to object's class (prototype). You can think of `prototype` in javascript as of reflection in C#